# How do I use the paging Laravel5 ? paginate() not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**Sql Query**

```
$result = DB::select("select * from commodities where group_id=$group ");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = DB::table('commodities')
              ->where('group_id', $group)
              ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

$users = DB::table('commodities')->where('group_id',$group_id)->paginate(10);

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

Answer (score 0):

**The eloquent way**

```
Commodities::where('group_id', $group)->paginate();
```

For this to work, you need to define your `Commodities` model.

Answer (score 0):

use laravel syntax instead of core mysql query

your code is:

```
$result = DB::select("select * from commodities where group_id=$group ");
```

replace your code with laravel blade syntax like following:

```
$result = DB::table('commodities')
              ->where('group_id', $group)
              ->paginate(10);
```

i use paginate(10) method in my code that gives 10 record per page

if you want more records per page than you replace 10 with records you want per page

you can use laravel eloquent for get your data like this:

```
$result = Commodities::where('group_id', $group)
                  ->paginate(10);
```

for use of laravel eloquent you have to create model "Commodities" in app/Models path like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Commodities extends Model {
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $table = 'commodities';
    ];
}
```

and if you use modal than add following line to top of your controller page like:

```
use App/Models/Commodities;
```

i hope its help you